# Loading a fixed width format file into R with different row / variable lengths

Tags: format, width, fixed

I am attempting to load the following data into R - using read.fwf:

sample of data

20100116600000100911600000014000006733839

20100116600000100912100000019600005648935

20100116600000100929100000000210000080787

20100116600000100980400000000090000000000

3010011660000010070031144300661101000

401001166000001000000001001

1010011660000020016041116664001338615001338115150001000000000000000000000000010001000100000000000000000000162002117592200001051

20100116600000200036300000001000005692222

however the first number in the row indicates which variables are coded in that line and they have different lengths so the 'widths' vector for lines starting with 1 is different from the 'widths' vector for lines starting with 2 and so on.

Is there a way I can do this without having to read the data in four times? (Note that each case has differing numbers of rows too)

Thank you, Maria

Comment: Provide a sample of the actual data rather than a screen shot of it. That way people can try out solutions and answer when the find one that work.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Yes, you can do it without reading the data multiple times (how would that help anyway?). Read the data with e.g., `readLines`, extract the first character from each line with `substr`, `split` the vector into a list of vectors, `mapply` `read.fwf` to the list of vectors and a list of width specifications.

Comment: And @Ista thank you for the answer: to answer your question, the issue I'm having is the size of the data (its the EU Farm Survey) and it is split up regionally whereas I need to split it by topic across all regions instead.  Rather than read the data in, process it and then split and export / merge the regions, I thought it would save time if I could just read in that data I was interested in.

Comment: edited to include some sample data rather than an image